# Problems with gensim install

Tags: python, gensim

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

'''
한국어 형태 분석된 자료를 word2Vec모델로 만드는 모듈
입력은 형태분석된 파일을 취함
한 줄에 한 문장씩
출력으로 model을 형성  
'''

import codecs
import gensim
import multiprocessing
import word2vec

import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

# 모델 configuration 설정 
config = {
   'min_count': 15,  # 등장 횟수가 15 이하인 단어는 무시
   'size': 300,  # 300차원짜리 벡터스페이스에 embedding
   'sg': 1,  # 0이면 CBOW, 1이면 skip-gram
    'batch_words': 10000,  # 사전을 구축할때 한번에 읽을 단어 수
    'iter': 10,  # 보통 딥러닝에서 말하는 epoch과 비슷한, 반복 횟수
    'workers': multiprocessing.cpu_count(),
}

modelTwitterNoStop = gensim.models.Word2Vec(**config)

class SentenceReader:

    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.filepath = filepath


    def __iter__(self):
         for line in codecs.open(self.filepath, encoding='utf-8'):
             yield line.split(' ')

# 사전과 학습을 형태분석된 파일을 가지고 행함
sentences_vocab = SentenceReader('corpusAllNewsNoTagNoStop.txt')
sentences_train = SentenceReader('corpusAllNewsNoTagNoStop.txt')

#model = gensim.models.Word2Vec()
modelTwitterNoStop.build_vocab(sentences_vocab)
modelTwitterNoStop.train(sentences_train)

#이렇게 학습된 모델을 저장
modelTwitterNoStop.save('modelTwitterNoStop')


### 모델 테스트 ##########
#다음 라인부터는 분리하여 별도로 Test모델 프로그램을 만들어 다양한 관계를 실험해 볼 수 있음

import codecs
import gensim
import multiprocessing

import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

##도 포함


#만들어 놓은 gensim 모델을 로딩
modelTwitterNoStop = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load('modelTwitterNoStop')


#most similar Test - 상위 10개의 유사한 벡터를 찾음.. 실제로 '일본'이 가장 높은    것으로 나
print ' '.join(["{}-{}".format(word, value) for word, value in 
(modelTwitterNoStop.most_similar(positive=[u"한국", u"도쿄"], negative=[u"서    울"], topn=10))])

print "\n"

# positive만 사용해서도 할 수 있으며 cosmul을 이용
print ' '.join(["{}-{}".format(word, value) for word, value in 
(modelTwitterNoStop.most_similar_cosmul(positive=[u"비선", u"최순실"], topn=20))])
print "\n"

#doesn't match Test
print modelTwitterNoStop.doesnt_match(u"정윤회 김종 박근혜 최순실".split())

print "\n"

#similarity Test
print modelTwitterNoStop.similarity(u"비선", u"정윤회")
print "\n"

# no.of vocab.. in this model
print modelTwitterNoStop
print "\n"
```

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py", line 840
    warnings.warn("detected Windows; aliasing chunkize to chunkize_serial")
UserWarning: detected Windows; aliasing chunkize to chunkize_serial

Comment: please add a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example to understand installation and usage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chunkize warning while installing gensim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41658568/chunkize-warning-while-installing-gensim)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem. Just for windows, it's handled differently.
If you don't want to see this message, you can use code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41658568/chunkize-warning-while-installing-gensim?answertab=votes#tab-top) answer

Answer (score 0):

This is just a warning not error. I also get it on windows whenever I import gensim. I don't think there is a problem with installation.