# Warning message after importing gensim module in Windows

Tags: python, nlp, warnings, semantics, gensim

When I tried to import gensim module in Windows, I end up with below error.

> c:\python27\lib\site-packages\gensim-3.0.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\gensim\utils.py:862: UserWarning: detected Windows; aliasing chunkize to chunkize_serial
>     **warnings.warn("detected Windows; aliasing chunkize to chunkize_serial")**

Is there any possibility to overcome this warning?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chunkize warning while installing gensim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41658568/chunkize-warning-while-installing-gensim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to suppress this warning just use the following code, before importing `gensim`:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore', category=UserWarning, module='gensim')
import gensim
```

Comment: Warnings are suppressed after trying this part. Thank you.