# how to fix the errors for gensim on window 10?

Tags: python, python-3.5

```
import gensim
```

> Warning (from warnings module):   File "E:\Program
> Files\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py", line 1212
> warnings.warn("detected Windows; aliasing chunkize to chunkize_serial") UserWarning: detected Windows; aliasing chunkize to
> chunkize_serial

I installed genism by using pip and then I tried to import genism.
but, there are some troubles as above.
How can I fix these problems?

Comment: This is not an error it is a warning. Check out this question it may help you bypass the warning https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41658568/chunkize-warning-while-installing-gensim

Answer (score 0):

You've faced with the [warning](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) message. Library you are using alerting that it would change default behavior due to the Window's peculiarities.

After you acknowledged the message, you could suppress it by adding this to the head of your program:

```
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings(
    'ignore',
    'detected Windows; aliasing chunkize to chunkize_serial',
)
```

Comment: after fixing that, I tried to execute my code but there are still some errors as below:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tmdgu\Desktop\NLP-master1\NLP-master\Ontology_Construction.py", line 55, in <module>
    , binary=True)

  File "E:\Program Files\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py", line 1282, in load_word2vec_format

    raise DeprecationWarning("Deprecated. Use gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format instead.")

DeprecationWarning: Deprecated. Use gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format instead.